# How can a transform PDF to PNG using ImageMagick (CGI/Perl)

Tags: perl, cgi, imagick

I've been searching about this . But i have found only a php example .
I'll appreciate Any idea , link or book you can suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way is to read and then write the file with the desired extension:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;

my $image = Image::Magick->new;
my $x = $image->Read('file.pdf');
$x = $image->Write('out.png');
warn "$x" if "$x";
```

the output files will be out-0.png, out-1.png, ... (one file for each page in original PDF) if the original file has multiple pages OR out.png if the PDF is only one page.